# Which one is correct? “If you were not my mother, I would disown you or If you were not my mother, I would have disowned you”

Tags: grammar

If you were not my mother, I would disown you **or** If you were not my mother, I would have disowned you.

Comment: Which do you think is correct and why?

Comment: @RogerSinasohn, sorry I need answer not question.

Comment: You might want to take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) because, as it stands, your question is off-topic for this site and is quite likely to be closed.  Note that _English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts._  You might want to try the site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: When did the not-disowning happen? Right now or in the past? Both could be correct but they mean subtly different things.

Answer (score 3):

They are both grammatically correct, but mean different things.

**If you were not my mother, I would disown you.**
This refers to the current moment.  You are mad at your mother and if she was anyone else, you would disown her.

**If you were not my mother, I would have disowned you.**
This refers to the past.  You were upset by your mother at some previous time and, at that time, you would have disowned her.  You may or may not still be upset about whatever happened.

Comment: Right, the first refers to a future possibility. The other is a past one.